# How do i check run-time errors with my cordova app in Visual Studio?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

My cordova app keeps crashing once i press the debug button on Visual Studio and brings up the index.html template, but then.

How do i see the run-time errors on Visual Studio?

Cheers

Comment: are you able to run your application on mobile, or it crashes before launch?

Comment: It runs on the mobile, but for around 3 seconds and then crashes, all i get is the response 'The program '[3616] WWAHOST.EXE' has exited with code 0 (0x0).' from the debug output.